# How can I iterate trough a jQuery object and wait for an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, events, iteration

Could anyone explain how to wait for an event to finish to move forward on the next iteration inside a for loop?
For example:

```
for ( i=0; i < item.length; i++ ) {
  $(video[i]).on('loadeddata', function() {
    // do my stuff
  })
}
```

Now, with this code I'm just adding an event listener to each video in the right order but obviously they will not load in this way. They will do my other stuff when they'll finish loading, and 'cause it's unpredictable, this ruins the order of the showed item on the page. So, how can I make the `for` loop to wait until the event finishes it's own stuff, before it goes to the next iteration?

EDIT: I'm adding more informations as requested. I actually have an object, containing HTML Elements. This object is retrieved with `var items = $('.db-gallery-item')`. The values of this object as I said are `<div>` elements, containing a container `<div>` with two elements inside for images (`<img>` and `<a>`) and a single `<video>` element for videos. Loading them i have to mantain their order, and so is required to wait for each element to load for make it visible and go working on the next.

SOLVED: Managed to solve this with the solution proposed by palash. This is the final code i used.

```
if(i_length > 0) {
    (async function() {
        for (i = 0; i < i_length; i++) {
            var item = $(items[i]);
            if($(item).find('.dbg-video').length == 1) {
                var video = $(item[0]).children().children();
                if(video[0].readyState > 3) {
                    item.removeClass('db-are-unloaded');
                    $grid.masonry('appended', $(item));
                }
                else {
                    await new Promise(resolve => video[0].addEventListener('loadeddata', resolve));
                    $(item[0]).removeClass('db-are-unloaded');
                    $grid.masonry('appended', $(item[0]));
                }
            } 
            else if($(item).find('.db-gallery-image').length == 1) {
                await new Promise(resolve => $(item[0]).imagesLoaded().done(resolve));
                $(item[0]).removeClass('db-are-unloaded');                                          
                $grid.masonry('appended', $(item[0]));
            }
        }
    }());
};
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BrainlessDesign/8aeg17uw/13/) working example.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < i.length; i++) will not work. Did you mean video.length instead of i.length?

Comment: @LajosArpad I'm sorry, i wrote that because i was thinking that my object dosn't have only videos but images too, so the number of elements is items.length.

Comment: np. Can you provide further information about video and item? As far as I understand, item is an array-like-object which contains elements and I assume video is an array of video elements. Can you elaborate this further to make sure we understand your exact situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for..await` logic like:

```
(async function() {
   for (i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
      await new Promise(resolve => video[i].addEventListener('loadeddata', resolve));
      // do my stuff
   }
}());
```

Here, for-loop iteration will wait until the `loadeddata` event on a `video` is finished.

**DEMO:**

```js
const fruitsToGet = ['apple', 'grape', 'pear']
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const getNumFruit = (fruit, delay) => sleep(delay).then(v => fruit);

// Since getNumFruit returns a promise, we can await the resolved value before logging it.
const init = async () => {
  console.log('Start')

  for (let i = 0; i < fruitsToGet.length; i++) {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) * 1000;
    const numFruit = await getNumFruit(fruitsToGet[i], rand)
    console.log(numFruit, 'delay: ' + rand)
  }

  console.log('End')
}
init()
```

Comment: I think the problem is each video loads at a different time, but he want the callbacks to be called in order. In your sample would be like instead of `sleep(1200)` you use `sleep(random)`, but the log would still be in the original order

Comment: As far as I understand, OP wants to wait for each `loadeddata` event to finish, then move on to next task. Also, `await` does that and it does matter when the event will finish, it will wait for all random times and only got to next statement when `await` is finished.

Comment: I see, but imagine video2 loads before video1. So video2 callback will only be placed after video1 triggered, meaning the callback for video2 will never be called, cause it already triggered

Comment: Yes, my problem is exactly this. I want to be showed in order but since every video loads in different times, i don't know how to do this. I'll try with your proposed solution. And let you know. Thank you guys

Comment: Sure. Please try out the proposed solution and see how it works.

Comment: @palaѕн Your snippet behaves differently than the code in the response. The snippet is calling the next loader on each callback. On the OP code every loader is called at the same time.

Comment: @ariel noted that too. however, i used the code on the response and id worked perfectly with some adjustments..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function array, like:

```
var functions = [];
var index = -1;

function doMyStuff(currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex = index + 1) {
        while ((index < functions.length) && functions[index]) {
            //Do something with $(video[index])
            index++;
        }
    }
}

for ( let j=0; j < video.length; j++ ) {
  $(video[j]).on('loadeddata', function() {
      functions[j] = true;
      doMyStuff(j);
  })
  functions[j] = false;
}
```

Explanation: We use a block-scoped variable for the loop so we will always know which video's event is fired. At the end of the loop `functions` will be an array, having only `false` elements (event did not occur yet) and upon each event, we first acknowledge which event occurred and then we call doMyStuff, which receives the index of the current element where the event has occurred. If that's the next in the queue, then its function is executed and all subsequent functions whose event already occurred.

A less custom way to do this is to apply a promise chain, see https://medium.com/@karenmarkosyan/how-to-manage-promises-into-dynamic-queue-with-vanilla-javascript-9d0d1f8d4df5